# Signs on independent variables change in VECM results

Tags: interpretation, cointegration, unit-root, vector-error-correction-model

I am estimating a VECM model and it was determined by the trace tests that there are two cointegration equations.  From this,  I proceeded  to estimate the β under this restriction that provides the normalized cointegration equation. The independent variables are significant at the 5 percent levels.

Now after obtaining the normalized equations, I treated the normalized variable as the   “dependent” variable and the remaining independent variables move to the RHS and the signs change.  In the normalized equation the sign is correct, but after this transformation the sign is the opposite. How can this be interpreted?

Comment: Could you give a small example? It looks as if you have something like $ax+by=c$, then move $by$ to the other side to get $ax=c-by$ and are surprised to discover that the sign has changed. This is trivial, but apparently your situation is somehow different. How? Also, how do you know that the sign is "correct" or "incorrect"?

Comment: Hello there no this is what I did:  ax+by=c, then move by to the other side to get ax=c−by.  Here is an example: The normalized cointegration equation for employment of men is 

z_2t=〖Employment of Men〗_(t-1)+120〖Capital Stock〗_(t-1)+179〖GDP Pennsylvania〗_(t-1)+36〖Tax〗_(t-1)-.509〖Trend〗_(t-1)-132
Treating the employment of men as the “dependent” variable, an estimated error correction model then becomes

〖Employment of Men〗_(t-1)=132-120〖Capital Stock〗_(t-1)-179〖GDP Pennsylvania〗_(t-1)-36〖Tax〗_(t-1)+.509〖Trend〗_(t-1)

Comment: You are not supposed to have lags of your variables in your cointegration vector as it is long-run (equilibrium) relations. Correct me if I am wrong but aren't you showing what what I did in my answer below? If the answer did not answer your question then let me know and I will change it. You can interpret the relationship you have just shown as a relationship explaining employment of men.

Comment: I think you lost z_2t in your transformed equation. I suggest you to edit the post when providing the extra details -- rather than post them in a comment. For me the question is still not clear; I do not understand what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 2):

When you look at your normalized eigenvectors $\hat{\beta}_{i}^{\prime}$ then the variable you normalized on should be one and the rest of the variables should appear in whatever sign they have divided by the normalized variable, e.g.:

$$\hat{\beta}_{1}^{\prime}=\left(0.07\,:\,-0.03\,:\,1.00\,:\,-0.29\,:\,0.57\right)$$ 
$$\hat{\beta}_{2}^{\prime}=\left(1.00\,:\,-1.02\,:\,-3.45\,:\,-8.51\,:\,8.00\right)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\hat{\beta}_{i}^{\prime}=\cdots$$

here the vecotor of variables is given as:

$$X_{t}=\left(m_{t}^{r}\,:\, y_{t}^{r}\,:\,\Delta p_{t}\,:\, R_{m,t}\,:\, R_{b,t}\right)^{\prime}$$.

In the above example it should be clear that we have normalized on $\Delta p_{t}$ in the first vector and $m_{t}^{r}$ in the second vector. When we want to interpret the relationship we can treat the normalized variables as the dependent variables in a linear regression so the signs of the other variables will change as we now interpret each vector as a relationship explaining the normalized variable (dependent variable if you want a comparison to linear regression), i.e. we move the variables to the other side. Using this, the first vector above can be interpreted as a relationship explaining the inflation rate:

$$\Delta p=0.29R_{m}-0.57R_{b}-0.07m^{r}+0.03y^{r}$$ and the second relationship can be interpreted as a money demand relationship:

$$m^{r}=1.02y^{r}+3.45\Delta p+8.51R_{m}-8.00R_{b}$$

We use the normalization so we are able to uniquely identify the $\beta$ vectors and by choosing to normalize on variables which lead to a meaningful economic relationship its a convenient way to let us interpret the cointegrating vectors as economic equilibrium relationships.

See the "[The Cointegrated VAR Model: Methodology and Applications](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-cointegrated-var-model-9780199285679?cc=dk&lang=en&)" by Katarina Juselius sections 7.5 and 7.6 which discusses exactly this and where the above has been adapted from.

Alternatively you cant take a look Eric Zivot's [lecture notes on cointegration](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ584/notes/cointegration.pdf), section 12.2.2 or  "[New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540401728)" by Lütkepohl.